# Normal subgroups and Homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

If we have a group $G$ s.t $|G|=15$. We also know $H \triangleleft G$ and that $H \cong \mathbb{Z}_3$.

Can we prove that $$
G \cong \mathbb{Z}_{15}?
$$

Comment: Yes we can! Consider first $G/H$, it turns out to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_5$. And that means, there's a subgroup of $G$ of order $5$. But since $5$ is prime, this subgroup is cyclic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $|G| = 3 \cdot 5$ and $3 \not\mid (5-1)$ by classification theorem ([Classify all groups with order $pq$, $p$ is not equal to $q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1889482/classify-all-groups-with-order-pq-p-is-not-equal-to-q)) you know that $G \simeq \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_5 \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{15}$

Answer (score 0):

You can prove that the Sylow subgroups are unique, that is normal, when you have a group of order $pq, p\lt q,p\nmid q-1$.  Then it follows that $G\cong\mathbb Z_p\times\mathbb Z_q\cong\mathbb Z_{pq}$.